# api возвращает строку в виде массива

Tags: php

API возвращает данные стройкой, в свою очередь строка в виде массива, такого вида:

```
{"Stages":[{"Events":[{"T1":[{"ID":10205,"I":[{"P":1,"Id":10205},{"P":2,"Id":999},{"P":5,"Id":999},{"P":6,"Id":2819},{"P":7,"Id":1238}],"Kn":1,"Gd":1,"Nm":"Villarreal"}],"Tr1":"2","Trh1":"0","T2":[{"ID":8372,"I":[{"P":1,"Id":8372},{"P":2,"Id":436},{"P":5,"Id":436},{"P":6,"Id":2839},{"P":7,"Id":1344}],"Kn":1,"Gd":1,"Nm":"Eibar"}],"Tr2":"1","Trh2":"0","IDs":[{"P":1,"ID":3424057,"d":1,"Sid":869369}],"Sg":1,"Esd":20200919210000,"Esid":6,"Epr":2,"Eps":"FT","Ewt":1,"Ern":2,"EO":25123},{"T1":[{"ID":8305,"I":[{"P":1,"Id":8305},{"P":2,"Id":488},{"P":5,"Id":488},{"P":6,"Id":2859},{"P":7,"Id":1029}],"Kn":1,"Gd":1,"Nm":"Getafe"}],"Tr1":"1","Trh1":"0","T2":[{"ID":8371,"I":[{"P":1,"Id":8371},{"P":2,"Id":742},{"P":5,"Id":742},{"P":6,"Id":2820},{"P":7,"Id":434}],"Kn":1,"Gd":1,"Nm":"Osasuna"}],"Tr2":"0","Trh2":"0","IDs":[{"P":1,"ID":3424051,"d":1,"Sid":869369}],"Sg":1,"Esd":20200919233000,"Esid":6,"Epr":2,"Eps":"FT","Ewt":1,"Ern":2,"EO":25123},{"T1":[{"ID":9910,"I":[{"P":1,"Id":9910},{"P":2,"Id":354},{"P":5,"Id":354},{"P":6,"Id":2821},{"P":7,"Id":281}],"Kn":1,"Gd":1,"Nm":"Celta Vigo"}],"Tr1":"2","Trh1":"1","T2":[{"ID":10267,"I":[{"P":1,"Id":10267},{"P":2,"Id":978},{"P":5,"Id":978},{"P":6,"Id":2828},{"P":7,"Id":1336}],"Kn":1,"Gd":1,"Nm":"Valencia"}],"Tr2":"1","Trh2":"0","IDs":[{"P":1,"ID":3424050,"d":1,"Sid":869369}],"Sg":1,"Esd":20200920020000,"Esid":6,"Epr":2,"Eps":"FT","Ewt":1,"Ern":2,"EO":25123},{"T1":[{"ID":96925,"I":[{"P":1,"Id":96925},{"P":2,"Id":27681},{"P":5,"Id":27681},{"P":6,"Id":24265},{"P":7,"Id":3504}],"Kn":1,"Gd":1,"Nm":"SD Huesca"}],"Tr1":"0","Trh1":"0","T2":[{"ID":8385,"I":[{"P":1,"Id":8385},{"P":2,"Id":2582},{"P":5,"Id":2582},{"P":6,"Id":4488},{"P":7,"Id":408}],"Kn":1,"Gd":1,"Nm":"Cadiz"}],"Tr2":"2","Trh2":"1","IDs":[{"P":1,"ID":3424053,"d":1,"Sid":869369}],"Sg":1,"Esd":20200920210000,"Esid":6,"Epr":2,"Eps":"FT","Ewt":2,"Ern":2,"EO":25123},{"T1":[{"ID":8581,"I":[{"P":1,"Id":8581},{"P":2,"Id":617},{"P":5,"Id":617},{"P":6,"Id":2849},{"P":7,"Id":1160}],"Kn":1,"Gd":1,"Nm":"Levante"}],"T2":[{"ID":9906,"I":[{"P":1,"Id":9906},{"P":2,"Id":258},{"P":5,"Id":258},{"P":6,"Id":2836},{"P":7,"Id":435}],"Kn":1,"Gd":1,"Nm":"Atletico Madrid"}],"IDs":[{"P":1,"ID":3424054,"d":1,"Sid":869369}],"Sg":1,"Esd":20200920220000,"Esid":5,"Epr":4,"Eps":"Postp.","Ern":2,"EO":24576},{"T1":[{"ID":8302,"I":[{"P":1,"Id":8302},{"P":2,"Id":859},{"P":5,"Id":859},{"P":6,"Id":2833},{"P":7,"Id":182}],"Kn":1,"Gd":1,"Nm":"Sevilla"}],"T2":[{"ID":10268,"I":[{"P":1,"Id":10268},{"P":2,"Id":439},{"P":5,"Id":439},{"P":6,"Id":2846},{"P":7,"Id":294}],"Kn":1,"Gd":1,"Nm":"Elche"}],"IDs":[{"P":1,"ID":3424056,"d":1,"Sid":869369}],"Sg":1,"Esd":20200920220000,"Esid":5,"Epr":4,"Eps":"Postp.","Ern":2,"EO":24576},{"T1":[{"ID":7878,"I":[{"P":1,"Id":7878},{"P":2,"Id":2001},{"P":5,"Id":2001},{"P":6,"Id":33779},{"P":7,"Id":5437}],"Kn":1,"Gd":1,"Nm":"Granada"}],"Tr1":"2","Trh1":"1","T2":[{"ID":9866,"I":[{"P":1,"Id":9866},{"P":2,"Id":223},{"P":5,"Id":223},{"P":6,"Id":2885},{"P":7,"Id":638}],"Kn":1,"Gd":1,"Nm":"Deportivo Alaves"}],"Tr2":"1","Trh2":"1","IDs":[{"P":1,"ID":3424052,"d":1,"Sid":869369}],"Sg":1,"Esd":20200920233000,"Esid":6,"Epr":2,"Eps":"FT","Ewt":1,"Ern":2,"EO":25123},{"T1":[{"ID":8603,"I":[{"P":1,"Id":8603},{"P":2,"Id":292},{"P":5,"Id":292},{"P":6,"Id":2816},{"P":7,"Id":746}],"Kn":1,"Gd":1,"Nm":"Real Betis"}],"Tr1":"2","Trh1":"2","T2":[{"ID":10281,"I":[{"P":1,"Id":10281},{"P":2,"Id":980},{"P":5,"Id":980},{"P":6,"Id":2831},{"P":7,"Id":136}],"Kn":1,"Gd":1,"Nm":"Real Valladolid"}],"Tr2":"0","Trh2":"0","IDs":[{"P":1,"ID":3424049,"d":1,"Sid":869369}],"Sg":1,"Esd":20200920233000,"Esid":6,"Epr":2,"Eps":"FT","Ewt":1,"Ern":2,"EO":25123},{"T1":[{"ID":8560,"I":[{"P":1,"Id":8560},{"P":2,"Id":879},{"P":5,"Id":879},{"P":6,"Id":2824},{"P":7,"Id":1264}],"Kn":1,"Gd":1,"Nm":"Real Sociedad"}],"Tr1":"0","T2":[{"ID":8633,"I":[{"P":1,"Id":8633},{"P":2,"Id":803},{"P":5,"Id":803},{"P":6,"Id":2829},{"P":7,"Id":696}],"Kn":1,"Gd":1,"Nm":"Real Madrid"}],"Tr2":"0","IDs":[{"P":1,"ID":3424055,"d":1,"Sid":869369}],"Sg":1,"Esd":20200921020000,"Esid":6,"Epr":2,"Eps":"FT","Ern":2,"EO":25123}],"Cid":42,"Ccd":"spain","Cnm":"Spain","Chi":0,"Ccntr":1,"Clive":1,"Sid2":198,"Scd":"primera-division","Sdn":"LaLiga Santander","Snm":"LaLiga Santander","Sds":"LaLiga","Ssm":750,"Scu":0,"SmCLT":750,"Slive":1,"Ses":380,"Spps":20}
```

Не могу понять как перебирать строку, что бы получить нужные данные, например нужно вытащить из данной строки "Villarreal", знаю что можно сделать поиск вхождений и регулярками вытягивать, но кажется это костыль, хотелось бы циклом вытягивать нужные данные

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Вообще, ваша `json` строка просто не валидна. В конце должно быть так: `"Spps":20}]}`

Вероятно, вы опечатались и вам все-таки приходит нормальная строка. Тогда преобразуйте ее в массив и работайте. Например, так:

```php
<?php

$str = '{"Stages":[{"Events":[{"T1":[{"ID":10205,"I":[{"P":1,"Id":10205},{"P":2,"Id":999},{"P":5,"Id":999},{"P":6,"Id":2819},{"P":7,"Id":1238}],"Kn":1,"Gd":1,"Nm":"Villarreal"}],"Tr1":"2","Trh1":"0","T2":[{"ID":8372,"I":[{"P":1,"Id":8372},{"P":2,"Id":436},{"P":5,"Id":436},{"P":6,"Id":2839},{"P":7,"Id":1344}],"Kn":1,"Gd":1,"Nm":"Eibar"}],"Tr2":"1","Trh2":"0","IDs":[{"P":1,"ID":3424057,"d":1,"Sid":869369}],"Sg":1,"Esd":20200919210000,"Esid":6,"Epr":2,"Eps":"FT","Ewt":1,"Ern":2,"EO":25123},{"T1":[{"ID":8305,"I":[{"P":1,"Id":8305},{"P":2,"Id":488},{"P":5,"Id":488},{"P":6,"Id":2859},{"P":7,"Id":1029}],"Kn":1,"Gd":1,"Nm":"Getafe"}],"Tr1":"1","Trh1":"0","T2":[{"ID":8371,"I":[{"P":1,"Id":8371},{"P":2,"Id":742},{"P":5,"Id":742},{"P":6,"Id":2820},{"P":7,"Id":434}],"Kn":1,"Gd":1,"Nm":"Osasuna"}],"Tr2":"0","Trh2":"0","IDs":[{"P":1,"ID":3424051,"d":1,"Sid":869369}],"Sg":1,"Esd":20200919233000,"Esid":6,"Epr":2,"Eps":"FT","Ewt":1,"Ern":2,"EO":25123},{"T1":[{"ID":9910,"I":[{"P":1,"Id":9910},{"P":2,"Id":354},{"P":5,"Id":354},{"P":6,"Id":2821},{"P":7,"Id":281}],"Kn":1,"Gd":1,"Nm":"Celta Vigo"}],"Tr1":"2","Trh1":"1","T2":[{"ID":10267,"I":[{"P":1,"Id":10267},{"P":2,"Id":978},{"P":5,"Id":978},{"P":6,"Id":2828},{"P":7,"Id":1336}],"Kn":1,"Gd":1,"Nm":"Valencia"}],"Tr2":"1","Trh2":"0","IDs":[{"P":1,"ID":3424050,"d":1,"Sid":869369}],"Sg":1,"Esd":20200920020000,"Esid":6,"Epr":2,"Eps":"FT","Ewt":1,"Ern":2,"EO":25123},{"T1":[{"ID":96925,"I":[{"P":1,"Id":96925},{"P":2,"Id":27681},{"P":5,"Id":27681},{"P":6,"Id":24265},{"P":7,"Id":3504}],"Kn":1,"Gd":1,"Nm":"SD Huesca"}],"Tr1":"0","Trh1":"0","T2":[{"ID":8385,"I":[{"P":1,"Id":8385},{"P":2,"Id":2582},{"P":5,"Id":2582},{"P":6,"Id":4488},{"P":7,"Id":408}],"Kn":1,"Gd":1,"Nm":"Cadiz"}],"Tr2":"2","Trh2":"1","IDs":[{"P":1,"ID":3424053,"d":1,"Sid":869369}],"Sg":1,"Esd":20200920210000,"Esid":6,"Epr":2,"Eps":"FT","Ewt":2,"Ern":2,"EO":25123},{"T1":[{"ID":8581,"I":[{"P":1,"Id":8581},{"P":2,"Id":617},{"P":5,"Id":617},{"P":6,"Id":2849},{"P":7,"Id":1160}],"Kn":1,"Gd":1,"Nm":"Levante"}],"T2":[{"ID":9906,"I":[{"P":1,"Id":9906},{"P":2,"Id":258},{"P":5,"Id":258},{"P":6,"Id":2836},{"P":7,"Id":435}],"Kn":1,"Gd":1,"Nm":"Atletico Madrid"}],"IDs":[{"P":1,"ID":3424054,"d":1,"Sid":869369}],"Sg":1,"Esd":20200920220000,"Esid":5,"Epr":4,"Eps":"Postp.","Ern":2,"EO":24576},{"T1":[{"ID":8302,"I":[{"P":1,"Id":8302},{"P":2,"Id":859},{"P":5,"Id":859},{"P":6,"Id":2833},{"P":7,"Id":182}],"Kn":1,"Gd":1,"Nm":"Sevilla"}],"T2":[{"ID":10268,"I":[{"P":1,"Id":10268},{"P":2,"Id":439},{"P":5,"Id":439},{"P":6,"Id":2846},{"P":7,"Id":294}],"Kn":1,"Gd":1,"Nm":"Elche"}],"IDs":[{"P":1,"ID":3424056,"d":1,"Sid":869369}],"Sg":1,"Esd":20200920220000,"Esid":5,"Epr":4,"Eps":"Postp.","Ern":2,"EO":24576},{"T1":[{"ID":7878,"I":[{"P":1,"Id":7878},{"P":2,"Id":2001},{"P":5,"Id":2001},{"P":6,"Id":33779},{"P":7,"Id":5437}],"Kn":1,"Gd":1,"Nm":"Granada"}],"Tr1":"2","Trh1":"1","T2":[{"ID":9866,"I":[{"P":1,"Id":9866},{"P":2,"Id":223},{"P":5,"Id":223},{"P":6,"Id":2885},{"P":7,"Id":638}],"Kn":1,"Gd":1,"Nm":"Deportivo Alaves"}],"Tr2":"1","Trh2":"1","IDs":[{"P":1,"ID":3424052,"d":1,"Sid":869369}],"Sg":1,"Esd":20200920233000,"Esid":6,"Epr":2,"Eps":"FT","Ewt":1,"Ern":2,"EO":25123},{"T1":[{"ID":8603,"I":[{"P":1,"Id":8603},{"P":2,"Id":292},{"P":5,"Id":292},{"P":6,"Id":2816},{"P":7,"Id":746}],"Kn":1,"Gd":1,"Nm":"Real Betis"}],"Tr1":"2","Trh1":"2","T2":[{"ID":10281,"I":[{"P":1,"Id":10281},{"P":2,"Id":980},{"P":5,"Id":980},{"P":6,"Id":2831},{"P":7,"Id":136}],"Kn":1,"Gd":1,"Nm":"Real Valladolid"}],"Tr2":"0","Trh2":"0","IDs":[{"P":1,"ID":3424049,"d":1,"Sid":869369}],"Sg":1,"Esd":20200920233000,"Esid":6,"Epr":2,"Eps":"FT","Ewt":1,"Ern":2,"EO":25123},{"T1":[{"ID":8560,"I":[{"P":1,"Id":8560},{"P":2,"Id":879},{"P":5,"Id":879},{"P":6,"Id":2824},{"P":7,"Id":1264}],"Kn":1,"Gd":1,"Nm":"Real Sociedad"}],"Tr1":"0","T2":[{"ID":8633,"I":[{"P":1,"Id":8633},{"P":2,"Id":803},{"P":5,"Id":803},{"P":6,"Id":2829},{"P":7,"Id":696}],"Kn":1,"Gd":1,"Nm":"Real Madrid"}],"Tr2":"0","IDs":[{"P":1,"ID":3424055,"d":1,"Sid":869369}],"Sg":1,"Esd":20200921020000,"Esid":6,"Epr":2,"Eps":"FT","Ern":2,"EO":25123}],"Cid":42,"Ccd":"spain","Cnm":"Spain","Chi":0,"Ccntr":1,"Clive":1,"Sid2":198,"Scd":"primera-division","Sdn":"LaLiga Santander","Snm":"LaLiga Santander","Sds":"LaLiga","Ssm":750,"Scu":0,"SmCLT":750,"Slive":1,"Ses":380,"Spps":20}]}';

// преобразовать строку в массив:
$arr = json_decode($str, true);

echo 'matches:';
foreach ($arr['Stages'][0]['Events'] as $event) {
    echo '<br />' . $event['T1'][0]['Nm'] . ' vs ' .  $event['T2'][0]['Nm'];
}
```

Вывод:

```
matches:
Villarreal vs Eibar
Getafe vs Osasuna
Celta Vigo vs Valencia
SD Huesca vs Cadiz
Levante vs Atletico Madrid
Sevilla vs Elche
Granada vs Deportivo Alaves
Real Betis vs Real Valladolid
Real Sociedad vs Real Madrid
```

Answer (score 0):

Используйте ф-цию [json_decode](https://www.php.net/manual/ru/function.json-decode.php), а потом можете уже вытягивать данные в цикле или еще каким-то способом.